# select multiple in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm new to HTML5 and I'm trying to test the `<select>` with the attribute `multiple` in forms on Google Chrome. I encounter two problems.

1. **Firstly, the options list changes in an ugly rectangle**

   [image: Ugly rectangle with multiple attribute]

   Whereas before it was "normal":

   [image: "normal" without multiple attribute]
2. My second problem is that, it seems that when i want to get the values of the select (by clicking on the button and in the code using javascript), only one is given...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

How do you travel?
<form  method="get" id=myForm" onsubmit="done();">
<select name="transport" multiple> <optgroup label="Ecological">
<option value="Feet" selected>By Foot</option>
<option value="Bike">By Bike</option> </optgroup>
<optgroup label="Non-ecological">
<option value="public transports">With public transports</option> <option value="motorbike">By motorbike</option> <option value="car">By car</option>
</optgroup> </select>

<button onclick="bdone();">button</button>

<script>

function bdone(){


var mesOptions=document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
alert(mesOptions.value); 
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for reading me!

Comment: "Ugly" is subjective, but the change in UI is something you have to live with. There isn't a standard UI widget which provides a way to select multiple items from a drop down menu. The ListBox style widget is the standard. (The alternative to living with it is to build you own UI widget (which won't be recognised by users) out of other elements and JavaScript.)

Comment: To your question #1 it appears like that because you included the `multiple` attribute in your `<select>` tag. Now if you don't want it to have the scrollbars, you can just add the attribute `size` eg: `<select multiple size="7">`

Comment: "My second problem" that would be two questions.

Answer (score 5):

1. **The Styling Issue**

   Just a note: the `multiple` attribute of the `select` element is not specifically *HTML5*.

   The styling is going to depend on the CSS styles that are being applied, both the user agent styles (the default browser styles), and the specific CSS on that page. Try putting it in a page by itself (or in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and see if you get the same styling.
2. **The selection issue**

   The `selectedOptions` property of the `select` element you get will contain an array of `HTMLOptionElement`s, all of which have the `value` property. See below:

   ### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/dPHmq/1/)

```
    function bdone(){
        var selectElem = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
        var mesOptions = selectElem.selectedOptions;
        for(var a=0;a<mesOptions.length;a++) {
            alert(mesOptions[a].value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know `multiple` has limited support for file inputs, but I've never heard of MSIE having issues with it on `select` elements.

Comment: Hmm, that must have been what I was thinking. I removed it from my answer. Thanks @Quentin.

Comment: @Pao: Which issue? Styling or getting the values?

Comment: @Pao: I've added a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/dPHmq/1/) to my answer to show you how it works. Are you familiar with the JavaScript console, to see debug messages? Instead of using `alert(msg)` you can use `console.log(msg)` or `console.dir(msg)` to write lines to the console. Most browsers have devtools where you can view the console. Try pressing `F12`.